# Quip in Modx needs to be replaced

Tags: php, package, comments, modx, modx-revolution

I am using Quip commenting extra in Modx. There are some distracting bugs but the biggest issue is that Quip is not Modx3 compatible and it is not being updated anymore.

Does anyone have recommendations for other more modern commenting extras in Modx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://en.modstore.pro/packages/users/tickets or https://en.modstore.pro/packages/utilities/easycomm
As far as I know both of them will be compatible with MODX3(probably already work, I know that the authors have already dealt with compatibility)

Alternately you can always use MODX-independendent disqus.com :)

Comment: Thank you.

I already tested Tickets and if I remember correctly, it didn't have notification emails about new comments. That is an important feature to get visitors back after new comments have been posted. I already contacted its author and I understood it is not developed anymore, at least by him?

Easycomm is new for me. I have to get familiar with it.

Btw, about disqus.com, are there any drawbacks of using it? Like ads placed by disquss, monthly fees etc.? I

Comment: @NikoSuominen Tickets: here is one of the optinos: Email notices about replies to ticket and comment.I believe it works now as you expected. The same notification EasyComm has, I've used it several times. As for Disqus.com I used its free version and only for comments, it was enough, there were no complaints (except that the user must log in to leave a comment, as far as I remember - it seems like an extra couple of clicks )

Comment: I need to test Tickets again. I tried also to find English documentation of EasyComm but only found Russian one. If Tickets or EasyComm  are unsuitable I think I will install a PHP based free commenting platform. There seems to be many of them available. Of course, Modx based extra would be the best.